# Can't empty trash, file says is in use, have tried everything

Tags: permission, trash

I'm trying to delete a Deleted Users folder but it won't let me, inside there's a Library folder with a VoiceTrigger folder, inside that there's a file called `SAT` when I try to directly delete that file I get this:

[image]

Doing `sudo rm -R` on the folder doesn't work either, it says I don't have permission. The file also looks like this when I do get info:

[image]

Comment: That's strange! The first image says that it failed to delete because the file could not be found? Not sure if you can try put it back (right click > put back), or just move it elsewhere using `mv` command and then try delete it again? Also I assume this isn't a system file because there's added layers of security if you're on macOS Big Sur

Comment: It won't let me put it back either, and trying to do anything inside the trash from terminal fails even with sudo.